# Можно ли установить кастомные атрибуты для стандартных view в android?

Tags: android

Допустим, динамически из полученного от сервера json - русуется список. Я хочу при клике на какой-нить Relativelayout делать http-запрос. Для этого я хочу засеттить какой-нибудь атрибут этому Relativelayout'y который будет содержать нужный мне url (типа как в html у тега `<a>` есть `href`). В обработчике кликов, я считываю атрибут элемента по которому кликнул и делаю запрос.

Нашел [инфу](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) только для случая, если используются кастомные view. Но меня интересует, можно ли устанавливать кастомные атрибуты стандартным view?

Comment: нет, только расширив стандартный класс своей реализацией (сделать кастомный View)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет вы так не сможете сделать. По сути кастомный атрибут на уровне кода виджета транслируется в биновые методы `get/set`

Например атрибут `android:text` в `TextView` имеет своим кодом два метода: `TextView.getText() и TextView.setText()`

То есть прописывая новые атрибуты, вы по сути должны переписать код виджета, что невозможно.

Реализуйте свой собственный виджет наследованием из стандартного, делайте в нем свои атрибуты - это совсем несложно.